# Using RegEx in Python finding words beginning with h, but not including html tags

Tags: python, html, regex

I'm trying to find all words beginning with h, but I need to exclude html tags, like  within this search. I have the code to find all the words starting with h:

```
\h\w+
```

I just don't know how to exclude things within my search specifically an html tag.

Comment: why dont you remove the html tags first then apply your regex

Comment: `\h` means? Do you mean words inside the tags? how are you getting your input?

Comment: \h means instances of h I believe plus the \w then searches for words starting with h. I'm trying to exclude specifically <html> and </html>. My input is a huge json file.

Comment: Please provide examples text and expected output

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Answer (score 0):

Use de exclude character `[^]`

```
[^<]h\w+
```

But i think this way may work better for what you want, since it generates a match for every word beginning with h that's not a

```
 (?!<)h\w+
```

Even better, do the following match:

```
 ((?!<)h\w+)
```

(close attention, there is a blank space just before the first `(` )

If the text is:

> html  teste homem carro agharro hzete  h

It will do a full match with " homem" and " hzete", being the first match groups the word you want. "homem","hzete".

I would recomend you a graphical regex validation tool, so you see live the expressions you are writing.
A good one is https://regex101.com/

Hope this helps.